# SSIS 2012 - Assigning variables to SQL Statement of an SQL Task

Tags: ssis, parameter-passing

I'm trying to map a parameter and variables to a SQL statement within a SQL Task

I'm connecting to an oracle DB - the connection is working fine.

My SQL Statement is: 
     insert into ? values(?,?)

I map package parameter: Param1 to (parametername) 0 in the mapping screen

variable1 to (parametername) 1 in the mapping screen and variable2 to (parametername) 3

Both the parameter and variables are datatype VARCHAR, and values are:

```
p1 = 'TEST_TABLE
v1 = 'TEST'
v2 = 'TEST'
```

However, I get an error "parameters no mapped correctly"

If I enter a sql statement like: insert into TEST_TABLE values('TEST','TEST') the record is inserted into the oracle database successfully.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

None of the connection managers available to the Execute SQL Task support parameterizing the table name, which is what you're trying to do with the first "parameter" in your query `insert into ? values(?,?)` (For further details, see "Using Parameter Names and Markers" in the MSDN article [Parameters and Return Codes in the Execute SQL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502).)

Answer (score 1):

The generally acceptend solution is to build the insert string on the fly and execute it. Here's an example: [Using Tablename as variable in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235370/using-tablename-as-variable-in-ssis)