# Using Tablename as variable in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I am trying to build a dynamic export using SSIS.

I set up a variable `TableName`-string and scoped to the package. 
I set up a sql task to find the table name I wanted and mapped the result set to above variable. (This task completes fine)

Then I have added another variable as `SQL("SELECT *  FROM [CRDATA].[dbo]."+@[User::TableName])` -string and scoped to the package and set up a dataflow task. Inside dataflow I add an OLEDB source and set up the input to SQL Variable and selected the above variable. This task fails.
The Error is:

```
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
 Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared..
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0  
Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Incorrect syntax near '+'..
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

I have set up delay validation to true on the sql task, dataflow and set the `validatemetadata` to `false` in the OLEDB Source property.

I have a feeling I made some mistake in the SQL Variable. Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Right-Click on your `SQL` variable and choose Properties. Is the EvaluateAsExpression property set to `False`?

Comment: why `SQL(` at the beginning? `SELECT * FROM [CRDATA].[dbo]."+(DT_WSTR,50)@[User::TableName]` should work fine

Comment: EvaluateAsExpression property for the SQL Var is set to true.

Comment: Sorry my mistake . i meant to say i have created a var called SQL and the string value is set to "SELECT * FROM [CRDATA].[dbo]."+@[User::TableName]